# How to link *.o object files into a kernel binary

Tags: gcc, linker, kernel

I have been studying kernel development. To develop my kernel binary, I am using following commands. However, everything was fine until the last C file (paging.o) was included. Although I checked the paging.c C code many times, it throws exceptions (invalid opcode interrupt 6). I doubt that there may be some mistakes in my compiling script. Please help. I work on a Windows 7 machine, using MinGW and Bochs.

```
nasm bootsec.asm -f bin -o bootsec.bin
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
nasm empty.asm -f bin -o empty.bin
gcc -ffreestanding -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c port_in_out.c -o port_in_out.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c mem.c -o mem.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c screen.c -o screen.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c isr.c -o isr.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c timer.c -o timer.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c paging.c -o paging.o
ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o main.o mem.o port_in_out.o screen.o isr.o timer.o paging.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.tmp kernel.bin
copy /b bootsec.bin+kernel.bin+empty.bin os-image.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong with the code or compiling script. Problem was with me. My bootsec.bin wrongly loads only 15 sectors of Kernel entry into memory. But my kernel entry becomes 29 sectors when paging.o is added.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there's lack of information in your question. You should provide sources for your code and for your "NUL" linker script.

I suggest that you use "objdump -D out.elf" to inspect the final elf file and make sure that the contents are sane there.

The only obvious thing in your compiling script that seems weird is the "-j .text" that you're passing to objcopy. This tells objcopy to only copy the ".text" sections from your object files. Are you sure that you want to do that for ".c" files ?
Most of ".c" files will compile to an object file with ".data", ".text", and ".bss" unless you're really very careful in your ".c" file.

You should control what sections should be discarded and what should stay in the final elf file through your linker script not through objcopy!

If you know for sure that your paging.c for example isn't going to need the ".data" and ".bss" sections then:

Are you sure that the code in paging.c is correct ? I'm guessing that this file controls MMU, and there's a very good chance that you will enable MMU in this file. If you enabled MMU the CPU will see a completely different view of the memory immediately ( after a few instructions actually, depends on your pipeline depth ). If that happens you need to make sure that the location that the CPU is executing from contain valid code ( usually by mapping your kernel twice ). If you didn't do that, your CPU might start executing garbage and consequently the invalid op that you're seeing.